# Share Data Between One Member Variable and Several Controls w/DoDataExchange /Force Update Controls on All Windows

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005

I have a VS 2005 C++ MFC project that contains several CDialog based windows.  The program communicates with a custom piece of hardware and displays different readings on the different windows.  The data is read from the hardware using a public static member function named ReadHardWare() of a class named CTools.  ReadHardWare() places the data read from the hardware in an array with global scope and each window has the ability to read from this array.  On each window I have an indicator that lights up showing that a read from hardware operation is in progress.  This indicator is a National Instruments 
Measurement Studio CNiButton class control.  CTools has a public static member variable of the CNiButton type named m_read_in_progress_status that I use to identify if a read operation is in progress (m_read_in_progress_status.Value == 1) or not (m_read_in_progress_status.Value == 0).  My goal is to have all the read indicators on all the opened windows show a read is in or not in progress at the same time.  I regularly use DoDataExchange to connect variables with controls but always on a one-to-one basis.  In this case I want several controls to connect with a single variable and to automatically update with that variable.

I seem to have two problems:

1) It seems that I am only able to have one control connect with the variable at the same time.  Apparently the only control that the variable shares data with is the first one instantiated (i.e. first window opened)

2) If I send a read command from the second window opened, not only does the read indicator on the second window still not show the read status but neither does the read indicator on the first anymore.  The only time any of the read indicators work is when I perform a read command from the first window opened.  The first window does not seem to want to update its controls when the second window is sending the read command.

So my questions are:

1) How can I allow two controls on two different windows to share the same member variable and update immediately when that member variable's value is changed?

2) How can I make the ReadHardWare() member function (or some other event) force the first window to update its controls even though it is not the window actively calling that function?

In the current case the first window is the parent of the second.  However this will not always be the case.

Below is an excerpt of my code.

//Globalvariables.cpp

```
NI::CNiButton CTools::m_read_in_progress_status;
```

//Tools.h

```
class CTools  
{  
public:  
    static ReadHardWare();  
public:  
    static  NI::CNiButton m_read_in_progress_status;  
}
```

//Tools.cpp

```
CTools::ReadHardWare()  
{  
    //Declare and initialize variables and other setup code is here  

    m_read_in_progress_status.Value == 1  //Set read in progress flag high  
    //Read operations here  
    m_read_in_progress_status.Value == 0  //Reset read in progress flag low  
}
```

//FirstWindow.cpp

```
#include "Tools.h"  
#include "SecondWindow.h"  
void CFirstWindow::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)  
{  
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);  
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_First_Window_Read_in_Progress_Indicator,   CTools::m_read_in_progress_status);  
}
```

//SecondWindow.cpp

```
#include "Tools.h"  
#include "FirstWindow.h"  
void CSecondWindow::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)  
{  
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);  
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_Second_Window_Read_in_Progress_Indicator, CTools::m_read_in_progress_status);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DDX_Control establishes an association between control identifier in dialog and particular instance of CWnd based object. I am not sure it's a good idea is to share the same object representing a button for two windows. I suggest to sligthly modify the design. You should create a timer for pooling read operation state. If state is changed you will update the button.

```
class CTools  
{  
public:  
    static void ReadHardWare();
public:  
    static int m_read_in_progress_status;  
}   

class CFirstWindow: CDialog
{
public:
    void OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
    {
        if(m_read_in_progress_status != CTools::m_read_in_progress_status)
        {
            m_read_in_progress_status = CTools::m_read_in_progress_status;
            m_button.SetCheck(m_read_in_progress_status);
        }
    }

private:
    int m_read_in_progress_status;  // Cached status
    NI::CNiButton m_button;
};
```

Comment: Vlad thanks for answering my question.  The problem I have with using a timer in CFirstWindow to poll the flag is that once it enters ReadHardWare() it will not trigger the timer in CFirstWindow until ReadHardWare() is finished despite the fact that the length of time it takes to read the hardware is much greater than the interval set on the timer.  So the read flag always has the same value (i.e. false) when the timer event is handled.  I need a way to force the timer event to take priority over finishing execution of ReadHardWare().

Comment: I think you need to create a separate working thread for reading data from the device.